# Set focus on input element after a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, focus

I have this clickable link,

```
`<a href="#" id="link">Clickable Link</a>`
```

and I have this `<input>` which will come out after the link is clicked,

```
    <input id="geo_title" type="text" value="some value" class="geo_title" />
```

in my script,

```
    $('#link').click(function(){

        $('input#geo_title').removeAttr('value');
        $("input#geo_title").focus();
    });
```

but sadly this does not focus the `<input>` element. What I wanted was that, after I click the link, I don't have to click the `<input>` element to be able to input something. What did I miss? Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's working in Chrome, see http://jsfiddle.net/ZgQPk/  In which browser do you have issues?

Comment: Also working in firefox, be more precise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine, you'll just have to prevent the default link action, so the browser won't try to follow it.

```
$('#link').click(function (evt){
  $('input#geo_title').removeAttr('value');
  $("input#geo_title").focus();
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it won't work. After the link is clicked, I still can't write on the `<input>` element without clicking it.

Comment: Does this: http://jsfiddle.net/VxXKt/ not work for you either? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3):

try to remove the default focus from the link by adding href=#!

```
<a href="#!" id="link">Clickable Link</a>
```

Comment: This was helpful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't wrapped your code in

`$( function() { });`

or

`$(document).ready( function() { });`